# Error getting mysql connection using golang

Tags: mysql, go

I'm new to golang and MySQL and I am using a dev box to create a simple web page using golang (code from the 2 files are way down below) to take input, store input into a database and display input on a webpage. Currently using MySQL locally as my database with my username as root and my password as abc, my database is also named abc.

At the top I have imported :

```
  import (
      _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" 

      "database/sql"
  )
```

When I serve my web page I call my connectDB function:

```
 func init(){
    INDEX_HTML , _ = ioutil.ReadFile("./templates/index.html")
    connectDb()
 }

 func connectDb(){
    //socket : var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 /* connection string examples : 
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
  user:password@tcp(localhost:5555)/dbname?tls=skip-verify&autocommit=true  

  TCP using default port (3306) on localhost: 
    user:password@tcp/dbname?charset=utf8mb4,utf8&sys_var=esc%40ped

  Use the default protocol (tcp) and host (localhost:3306):
    user:password@/dbname

  No Database preselected:
    user:password@/
*/

   db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:abc@/abc")

    log.Println("DB: ", db)

    checkErr(err)

    // Open doesn't open a connection. Validate DSN data:
    checkErr(err)
 }
```

My understanding and according to https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
SQL.open returns a * sql.DB, and when the program hits following code above:

```
/* At the top of my code i have var db = *sql.DB */
log.Println("DB: ", db)
```

I get the following in the command prompt with all types of example connection strings noted in the code comments above:

**DB:  &{0x99c410 root:abc@/abc 0 {0 0} [] [] 0 0xc820072180 false map[] map[] 0 0 0 < nil >}**

My MySQL database is running fine locally through the command line with the given username and password and I can get a few items with the following queries inserted manually.

```
mysql>
mysql> select * from ListItems
     -> ;
+-------+
| items |
+-------+
| item1 |
| item2 |
+-------+
```

I'm trying to understand what the message is and how I can go about connecting to the mysql database to run queries and insert into the database.

Maybe there is something wrong with my connection string? An example of my error while trying to insert into the database:

```
016/06/20 02:22:36 http: panic serving 10.1.0.5:41861: 
runtime error: invalid    
memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 7 [running]:

net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc82006c380)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1389 +0xc1
panic(0x74ef00, 0xc82000a0c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:443 +0x4e9
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:778 +0xac9
database/sql.(*DB).exec(0x0, 0x812b60, 0x26, 0xc82003fa70, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc82000b201, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1021 +0x87
database/sql.(*DB).Exec(0x0, 0x812b60, 0x26, 0xc82003fa70, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1009 +0xbe
main.AddListHandler(0x7f56da7ac9b0, 0xc82006f6c0, 0xc8200f21c0)
    /home/cabox/workspace/src/github.com/user/hello/main.go:26 +0x36c **<---**
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x859f70, 0x7f56da7ac9b0, 0xc82006f6c0, 0xc8200f21c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1618 +0x3a
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xc820010b10, 0x7f56da7ac9b0, 0xc82006f6c0, 0xc8200f21c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x17d
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc82006c180, 0x7f56da7ac9b0, 0xc82006f6c0, 0xc8200f21c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2081 +0x19e
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc82006c380)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1472 +0xf2e
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2137 +0x44e
```

As I look at line 26 in main.go I have:

```
  db.Exec("INSERT INTO ListItems(items) Values(?)" , (r.Form["item"][0]))
```

**Here is the minimal code sample:**

**project/templates/index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>

<h1>Enter item to add to list:</h1><br>
<form action="/addlist" method="post">
<input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Enter Item to add to list"><br>
<input type ="submit" class="add" value="Add To List"><br>
</form>
```

**projects/main.go ..  using go build main.go**

```
package main

import (
 "net/http"
 "fmt"
 "io/ioutil"
 "log"
_"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
 "database/sql"
)

var  INDEX_HTML []byte // holds the raw html of index.html inside /templates
var db *sql.DB // pointer to sql.open which returns a sql.db 


func main(){
   fmt.Println("starting server on port 8080")
   http.HandleFunc("/", IndexHandler)
   http.HandleFunc("/addlist", AddListHandler)
   http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func AddListHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  r.ParseForm()
  log.Println("adding list: ", r.Form["item"][0])
  db.Exec("INSERT INTO ListItems(items) Values(?)" , (r.Form["item"][0])) /*error*/
  if(db == nil){log.Println("DB is nill")}

  http.Redirect(w,r,"/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}

func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  log.Println("GET /")
  w.Write(INDEX_HTML)
}

func init(){
  INDEX_HTML , _ = ioutil.ReadFile("./templates/index.html")
  connectDb()
}

func connectDb(){
  //socket : var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  /* connection string examples : 
   db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname")
   user:password@tcp(localhost:5555)/dbname?tls=skip-verify&autocommit=true   
   TCP using default port (3306) on localhost: 
     user:password@tcp/dbname?charset=utf8mb4,utf8&sys_var=esc%40ped
  Use the default protocol (tcp) and host (localhost:3306):
    user:password@/dbname
  No Database preselected:
    user:password@/
  */

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:abc@/abc")
    log.Println("DB: ", db)
    checkErr(err)

   // Open doesn't open a connection. Validate DSN data:
    checkErr(err)
 }

 func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
    }else{
      log.Println(err)
    }
 }
```

Comment: That is golang printing your `DB` instance. Just what you asked it to do in `log.Println("DB: ", db)`. What did you expected to see? Everything seem to be working fine.

Comment: hmm I thought I'd see some form of my database.. Its my first time using golang and mysql. I copied my error as well as the code snippet that was causing it.

Comment: Thanks for including the error. But still I can't figure out much. Maybe others could help if you include a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I realize that I was looking at a DB instance but the <nil> value at the end began to confuse me. I was expecting something there to represent my database.

Comment: Ive included my code sample that I used for this as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the global `db` variable you declare by `var db *sql.DB` is never assigned a value. So it keeps its default value which is `nil`. And trying to dereference a nil pointer gives you the error.

You probably think that in the `init` function you are assigning this variable the newly created `DB` instance. But `:=` creates a new local variable to hold the new `DB` instance. The global `db` variable is left untouched. See [example](https://play.golang.org/p/JsCOAynUbN).

So instead do,

```
var err error
db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:abc@/abc")
```

Also from my experience using a global variable when you can avoid it leads to errors hard to debug. (like this one.) I think you can avoid it by making `connectDb` return a `DB` instance.

Comment: I made these changes: 

database, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:abc@/abc")
db = database
 
and it throws no error

although inside my addlisthandlerfunction() this query doesnt insert into my database:
log.Println("adding list: ", r.Form["item"][0]) <-- prints out the text box value
db.Exec("INSERT INTO ListItems(items) Values($1)" , r.Form["item"][0])

Comment: i guess my question would be how would i get my addlisthandler function to be able to access that instance provided by sql.Open("mysql", "root:abc@/abc")?

Comment: [DB.Exec](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) returns a result and an error. Check those.

Comment: Fixed the error and now the application works :D Thanks for the help.